# Problema con interfaz grafica con un boton java

Tags: java, interfaz

Hola buenas empecé hace poco en java utilizando netbeans y estoy creando una ventana que contenga contraseña y usuario para poder decir si es correcta o incorrecta la contraseña (el usuario debería ser Admin y la contraseña también) pero a la hora de ejecutar el proyecto el botón de "enviar" agarra todo el programa. dejo abajo mi código con tambien una foto para ver si alguno me puede ayudar.

Código:

```
package Interfaz;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Formulario4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    
    private JLabel label1, label2, label3;
    private JButton boton1;
    private JTextField tf1;
    private JPasswordField pss1;

    public Formulario4() {
        label1 = new JLabel("Usuario: ");
        label1.setBounds(10,10,100,30);
        add(label1);
        
        label2 = new JLabel("");
        label2.setBounds(10,70,250,30);
        add(label2);
        
        label3 = new JLabel("Contraseña: ");
        label3.setBounds(10,40,100,30);
        add(label3);
        
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(60,17,100,20);
        add(tf1);
        
        pss1 = new JPasswordField();
        pss1.setBounds(100,45,100,20);
        pss1.setEchoChar('*');
        pss1.setToolTipText("Ingrese Contraseña");
        add(pss1);
        
        boton1 = new JButton("Enviar");
        boton1.setBounds(170,40,80,25);
        add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);  
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == boton1) {
            String usuario = tf1.getText();
            String password = pss1.getText();
        if(usuario == "admin" && password == "admin"){
            label2.setText("A ingresado correctamente");
            
        } else {
            label2.setText("Usuario o contraseña inválidos");
        }
     }
  }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Formulario4 form1 = new Formulario4();
        form1.setBounds(0, 0, 340, 200);
        form1.setVisible(true);
        form1.setResizable(true);
        form1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

[image: foto]

Comment: "Todo el programa" quiere decir que agarra todo el alto y ancho del panel? Lo otro es que así no se lee el contenido de un campo JPassword

Comment: si agarra todo el alto y el ancho del panel, ¿y como se lee el contenido de un campo JPassword?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes al menos tres problemas. El primero es el layout del JFrame, que no le dices nada e incluso si no añades el botón, los demás campos se superponen por falta de información.

La solución a eso es inicializar el layout.

El segundo problema es que no leíste la documentación y no te esforzaste en revisar qué quería decir el comentario. Así no se leen los campos JPassword y cualquier IDE te va a decir que ese método esta deprecado. Usas getPassword y eso te devuelve un array de char, `char[]` que debes transformar en un String.

El tercer problema, el peor de todos, es que estás comparando dos String usando `==` y eso no hace lo que crees que hace. Eso compara las instancias de String, no el contenido. Se usa el método `equals`.

Supongo que no vas a leer nada de esto y sólo quieres resolver tu tarea. Aquí queda tu tarea. Ojalá me equivoque ;)

```java
public class Formulario4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

    private JLabel label1, label2, label3;
    private JButton boton1;
    private JTextField tf1;
    private JPasswordField pss1;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Formulario4() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        label1 = new JLabel("Usuario: ");
        label1.setBounds(10,10,100,30);
        this.getContentPane().add(label1);

        label2 = new JLabel("");
        label2.setBounds(10,70,250,30);
        this.getContentPane().add(label2);

        label3 = new JLabel("Contraseña: ");
        label3.setBounds(10,40,100,30);
        this.getContentPane().add(label3);

        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(105,17,100,20);
        this.getContentPane().add(tf1);

        pss1 = new JPasswordField();
        pss1.setBounds(105,45,100,20);
        pss1.setEchoChar('*');
        pss1.setToolTipText("Ingrese Contraseña");
        this.getContentPane().add(pss1);

        boton1 = new JButton("Enviar");
        boton1.setBounds(205,45,80,20);
        this.getContentPane().add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == boton1) {
            String usuario = tf1.getText();
            String password = new String(pss1.getPassword());
            if(usuario.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){
                label2.setText("Ha ingresado correctamente");

            } else {
                label2.setText("Usuario o contraseña inválidos");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Formulario4 form1 = new Formulario4();
        form1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
        form1.setVisible(true);
        form1.setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

PD. Si ves, hay una cosa más añadida: El comportamiento de cierre por defecto, para que el programa no se quede ejecutando cuando cierres el panel.

Comment: Primero que todo gracias por ayudarme y segundo que nada no hay por que ser así, estoy intentando aprender solo y no tengo ningún tipo de ayuda mas que youtube , stackoverflow y algún que otro foro de internet.

Comment: @Afix42 Lamento si pareció regaño. Esto de venir acá es voluntario y yo estoy acá parchando log4j mientras respondo, pero es triste cuando uno le comenta a las personas y la respuesta es "dígame cómo" en vez de ir y mirar lo que te están indicando. Programar es divertido porque puedes probar y dañar sin que pase mayor cosa, hay que probar y leer la documentación, los ejemplos que hay en todas partes, etc. Te deseo suerte y ojalá avances rápidamente! :)  PD Si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que otros sepan que la pregunta tuvo solución. Usa el check junto a los votos